# Use changing range value from end of column and use it in a formula next column excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

Although I can easily create the formula necessary in a static worksheet, I want to be able to do this in VBA for my client where the Total Value in Column Q will move say, from Q41 to Q100 etc... I know how to select the value by using:

```
Range("Q1").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 0).Select
```

However, I would like to know the correct syntax in Cell R1 where I wish to type the formula. Currently, it is counting the column where the total is and expressing it as follows:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]/R[40]C[-1]"
```

However, that won't be useful if the total is on a different row number.
Enclosed is a clip from the spreadsheet with the manual formula shown to demonstrate what I am after.

[Manual Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDldN.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
With Range("Q1", Range("Q1").End(xlDown)).Offset(0, 1)
    .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Formula = "=RC[-1]/R" & .Cells(.Rows.Count).Row & "C[-1]"
End With
```

Comment: I guess I need to read up on the Resize and Rows. Count attributes. Your code worked.

Comment: I modified your code (see below) to find another total at Column 9 (i.e. -10) and used your Row.Count method however, that total sits at Row 43 so I added +3 to the Column to make it work. But I am thinking if the total moves to Row 44...45 etc what is the way around this?

 `With Range("R1", Range("R1").End(xlDown)).Offset(0, 1) 'Find Total and Input Formula dynamically
  .Resize(.Rows.Count).Formula = "=RC[-1]*R" & .Cells(.Rows.Count + 3).row & "C[-10]"
End With